# Rails On Fargate And Configuring Worker Count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm looking to run a Rails app using fargate. I'm used to running Rails in the traditional setup that uses nginx and puma. I can configure the worker and thread count just fine.

What is the standard way to run on Fargate? Do you just start a task with rails s? In this case you would only be able to serve 1 request at a time for each container. Does anyone run puma on a container?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the standard way to run on Fargate?

The standard way is to continue using Nginx and Puma. Deploying your Docker containers to Fargate doesn't change the way you should run Rails at all. You will need two docker containers in your ECS task definition, one running Nginx and one running your Rails app via Puma.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. So traditionally there would be one instance of nginx per puma instance. Is this still the same setup? Or does one nginx serve multiple puma containers?

Comment: You would have one Nginx container and one Puma/Rails container per task definition. So each Fargate instance would be running one Nginx instance and one Puma instance.

Comment: Cheers for the guidance